# Complex Number Systems involving trig.

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

I have to integrate from $0$ to $1$ in complex numbers the quantity $e^{-t} \cdot  sin(2\pi t)$

I know what sign should look like if that $2\pi$ was not there, but it is, so do  i just but it in for the variable and evaluate or to I perhaps use a substitution for $2\pi$ and work with that?

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int e^{-x}\sin(2\pi x)\,dx=e^{-x}\sin(2\pi x)-2\pi \int e^{-x}\cos(2\pi x)\,dx$$
$$=e^{-x}\sin(2\pi x)-2\pi\left(
e^{-x}\cos(2\pi x)+
2\pi\int e^{-x}\sin(2\pi x)\,dx
\right)$$
$$=e^{-x}\sin(2\pi x)-
2\pi e^{-x}\cos(2\pi x)-
4\pi^2I$$

Solving for $I$ we get $$I=e^{-x}\frac{\sin(2\pi x)-
2\pi \cos(2\pi x)}{1+4\pi^2}$$

And the definite integral is equal to
$$\int_0^1 e^{-x}\sin(2\pi x)\,dx=
\frac{2\pi}{1+4\pi^2}-
\frac{2\pi}{e(1+4\pi^2)}=
2\pi\frac{e-1}{e(1+4\pi^2)}$$